# sampling technique: lower error in estimation on using higher sampling rate

Tags: sampling

I am using sampling to estimate characteristics of a population. My sampling ratio is 32. I take N/32 samples, calculate their sum and multiply by 32. Then I compare it to actual value to get error. It is 3.67%.

Then I take sampling ratio as 64 and do the same and get error as 3.62%. Generally one would expect a higher sampling-error.

Is that possible. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is certainly possible.  You could be luckier in your sampling of 1 in 64 and have no error at all.  Imagine a population of 640, with 600 of value 0, 20 of value -1 and 20 of value 1.  The average is 0.  If your 10 samples are all 0, the average will be exactly right.  If your 20 samples (for the 1/32 case) include a couple of 1's and no -1's there will be an error.